# complete the square $ y^2 + z^2 + yz - 5y - 5z $ and showing it is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, quadratic-forms

I want to show that the expression : 
$$ y^2 + z^2 + yz - 5y - 5z = -8$$
is bounded. I was thinking about writing the expression in the form of squares, just like here:

$$ 1= x^2 + y^2 + xy - 3x - 3y = [x-1 + \frac 1 2 (y-1) ]^2 + \frac 3 4 (y-1)^2 $$

do you have any idea how to do this ? If you have any other method, I'm also taking it.

Comment: I have got $$\left( z+y/2-5/2 \right) ^{2}+ \left( y-5/2 \right) ^{2}+7/4-1/4\,
 \left( y-5 \right) ^{2}
$$

Comment: Does it help? How did you found it? I m searching for a method

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by an equation being bounded.

Comment: If you merely want to show that the graph of the equation is bounded, as opposed to actually finding bounds, then is it not sufficient to show that the discriminant is negative? If the discriminant is negative, then the graph is an ellipse, and an ellipse is bounded. QED

Comment: I don't know about ellipses, but yes this is what i want to do. I e Showing that the graph is bounded

Comment: The general equation of a conic section is $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$. If the discriminant $B^2-4AC<0$, then it is the graph of an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section) and is, therefore, bounded.

Comment: $ y^2 + z^2 + yz - 5y - 5z=-8 $ is actually equivalent to $\dfrac{(y+z)^2}3+\left(y-z-\dfrac{10}3\right)^2=\left(\dfrac23\right)^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by putting the $yz$ term inside a square and write
$$y^2 + z^2 + yz - 5y - 5z = {(y + z)^2 \over 2} + {y^2 \over 2} + {z^2 \over 2} - 5y - 5z$$
Next, put the $5y$ and $5z$ terms inside squares:
$${(y + z)^2 \over 2} + {y^2 \over 2} + {z^2 \over 2} - 5y - 5z = 
{(y + z)^2 \over 2} + {(y - 5)^2 \over 2} + {(z-5)^2 \over 2} - 25$$
So your points are the $(y,z)$ for which 
$${(y + z)^2 \over 2} + {(y - 5)^2 \over 2} + {(z-5)^2 \over 2} = 17$$
So in particular, ${(y - 5)^2 \over 2}$ and ${(z-5)^2 \over 2}$ are both at most $17$. So $|y- 5|, |z - 5| \leq \sqrt{34}$ and your set is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

$$y^2+z^2+yz-5y-5z+8=0$$

Let's first deal with all the terms in $y$. Note that $(y+\frac z2)^2$ has a term $yz$ and $(y-\frac 52)^2$ has a term $-5y$. To eliminate the fractions first multiply by $4$.

$$4y^2+4z^2+4yz-20y-20z+32=0$$

Then, taking the two clues about eliminating $y$ we take a summand $$(2y+z-5)^2=4y^2+4yz-20y+z^2-10z+25$$ so that $$(2y+z-5)^2+3z^2-10z+7=0$$

If we now multiply by $3$ we obtain $$3(2y+z-5)^2+9z^2-30z+21=0$$ or, completing the square in the $z$ terms: $$3(2y+z-5)^2+(3z-5)^2=4$$

Which may give you what you want - this bounds $z$ and by symmetry $y$ can be bounded too.

Comment: @user376343 Corrected. Feel free to edit such typos.

Answer (score 2):

The graph of  $ y^2 + z^2 + yz - 5y - 5z = -8$  is clearly symmetric about the line $y=z$.

To get it into a more familiar form, apply the following transformation (rotate $45^o)$:

$x=\dfrac y{\sqrt2}-\dfrac z{\sqrt2};   \; w=\dfrac y{\sqrt2}+\dfrac z{\sqrt2}.$

The equation then becomes $x^2+w^2+\dfrac{w^2-x^2}2-5\sqrt2w=-8$ or $x^2+3w^2-10\sqrt2w=-16.$

Now complete the square to get $x^2+3\left(w-\dfrac{5\sqrt2}3\right)^2=-16+\dfrac{50}3=\dfrac23.$

This is a familiar form for an  ellipse.

In any event, from this equation it is clear that $x$ and $w$ -- and therefore $y$ and $z$ -- are bounded.